# How can I make it so that holding down Shift can capitalize a maximum of 1 letter?

Tags: windows-registry, shortcuts, speed, typing, shift

My biggest personal problem with typing is that I tend to accidentally captilize the first two letters in a word when using Shift. For example, I'd type "GEorge" instead of "George". Then I have to backspace and retype the whole word. Is there a way I can make it so that Shift only works on that first letter, then I have to release and press again for a second? Even better if I can give it a shortcut to enable or disable it, not unlike the shortcuts for things like Sticky Keys.

Comment: Where do you need this? Many office suites automatically do this through auto-correct.

Comment: however, if he is not using office, the problem still occors

Answer (score -1):

Simply let go of the shift key after typing the first letter.

Comment: While I appreciate the humor of this answer, I do believe that the OP could have thought of this one himself

Comment: It's true that it's humorous but it's also the correct answer